# Decrease data flow in get firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in my bd realtime database in firebase google

[image]

I would like to retrieve only the data from the rooms, without the data from the children, but when I add a "listener" on no value, the data returned includes the children. How to do this to reduce the amount of data transferred?

```
roomRef.on('value',
    (snapshot) => {
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp0FN.png)

Answer (score -1):

The Firebase SDKs always retrieve full nodes. There is no way through the JavaScript SDK to get the keys without also getting the child data.

If you find yourself needing this, it typically means that you've [nested data  more than you should](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

For example, in your case I'd recommend putting the questions in a separate higher-level node, likely with the same key `-McyCb...`. That way you can initially load the other non-question data with one call, and then perform an extra call when you need to questions